# PHP - Regular expression to extract all paths to the images from within the CSS file

Tags: php, css, regex, background-image

I'm trying to find the regular expression, which would extract all paths from within the css file. I've searched and all I could find were these two posts, which don't actually seem to work:

[PHP - extract image paths from css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688508/php-extract-image-paths-from-css)

[Why doesn't this PHP regular expression extract the url from the css value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677354/why-doesnt-this-php-regular-expression-extract-the-url-from-the-css-value)

What I want to get is the array like so:

```
array(0 => 'image/header.gif', 1 => 'image/footer.png') etc.
```

Any idea what the regular expression would be to extract it - and please bear in mind that there might be no white space between the characters or there might also be an extra space in between the opening and closing brackets of the url().

I'm using the following to process the css and extract the paths (but obviously I don't have the right expression to do it the way I want):

```
$images = array();                  
if (preg_match_all($regex, $cssContent, $matches)) {
    $images = $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: Do you have a sample from your css file?

Comment: Hi Mellamokb - any css file would do - I'm trying different websites and differently written css files.

Answer (score 5):

got it sorted. For those of you who are interested to know - here's the expression which extracts all of the paths to the images from the css file:

```
'/url\(\s*[\'"]?(\S*\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png))[\'"]?\s*\)[^;}]*?/i'
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, I would imagine:

```
/url\s*\(\s*['"]([^'"]+)['"]\s*\)/
```